# How avoid TCP packet fragmentation?

Tags: tcpip

I'm using an Arduino Uno with an Ethernet Shield and the arduino.cc [Ethernet library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) for a custom TCP-based message-exchanging chat-like protocol. Specifically I'm using the [Client class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConstructor) with its `print()`
and `println()` methods. It works.

But on each single `print()` or `println()` call a whole TCP packet is sent. Also if just one byte is printed, a whole TCP packet is sent over the IP layer. I mean there's a lot of TCP packets with very few data inside. In other words there's a big overhead.

For example take this message that my Arduino successfully sends and my server successfully receives:

```
i-am EEEEEEEE-EEEEEEEE-EEEEEEEE-EEEEEEEE\r\n
```

The code is the following:

```
stream.print("i-am");
stream.print(' ');
for (byte i = 0 ; i < SERIAL_CODE_LENGTH ; i++){
  if (  i % 4 == 0 && i != 0 ){
    stream.print('-');
  }
  if (serialCode[i] < 16){
    stream.print('0');
  }
  stream.print(serialCode[i], HEX);
}
stream.println();
```

All that `EE` are hexadecimal byte values from an array and they are fine. But I can see from Wireshark that **those 42 bytes** (that could be fit in a single packet) **are sent in 22 TCP packets** (one for each `print` call in my code)!

**How can I avoid this fragmentation? Is there a way to use an hardware or software buffer to group data before to send ([Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm))?**

With other SDKs the data are buffered by default and they're sent when the buffer is full or when an explicit "push" or "flush" call occurs. I checked Client `flush` method and it looks to be a different beast...

Comment: Use a better Ethernet library.

Comment: Any suggestions for a better library, @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams?

Comment: It is possible to write an ethernet library that buffers directly in the W5100 and uses an efficient SPI interleaving algorithm for transfer. Please see the Cosa W5100/W5200 device drivers for example. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/W5100/W5100.hh

Comment: To be honest, at the point I'm now with the sketch quite finished, I'm already thinking to replace those stream.print() with a sort of bufferredPrint() and to finalise them with bufferFlush(). But I still ask to myself if there is a better and feasible way to use the hardware buffer of the Ethernet shield and to do not upset the entire sketch.

Comment: Have a look at the example sketch CosaShellTelnetServer; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa-Shell/blob/master/examples/CosaShellTelnetServer/CosaShellTelnetServer.ino You can use this to check the performance difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to derive the EthernetClient class to override the write method and to add a sendNow method. In this way I still can:

1. Use any print method version simply by inheritance;
2. Pass the BufferedEthernetClient objects to function taking generalized Stream references (functions that can be used also with Serial, Wire, SD...).

---

### Code

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 64

class BufferedEthernetClient : public EthernetClient {
  public:
    BufferedEthernetClient();
    virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *buf, size_t size);
    virtual void sendNow();
  private:
    byte buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    byte bufferCount;
};

BufferedEthernetClient::BufferedEthernetClient(){
  bufferCount = 0;
}

size_t BufferedEthernetClient::write(const uint8_t *buf, size_t size){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
    buffer[bufferCount] = *(buf + i);
    bufferCount++;
    if (bufferCount >= BUFFER_SIZE){
      sendNow();
    }
  }
  return size;
}

void BufferedEthernetClient::sendNow(){
  if (bufferCount){
    bufferCount -= EthernetClient::write(buffer, bufferCount);
  }
}
```

### Example

I use it in this way:

```
void printSerialCode(Stream & stream){
  for (byte i = 0 ; i < SERIAL_CODE_LENGTH ; i++){
    if (  i % 4 == 0 && i != 0 ){
      stream.print('-');
    }
    if (serialCode[i] < 16){
      stream.print("0");
    }
    stream.print(serialCode[i], HEX);
  }
}

BufferedEthernetClient client;
...
client.print("i-am");
client.print(' ');
printSerialCode(client);
client.println();
client.sendNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its `stream.print()` that is causing the problem.  Write the data into a string and then use a SINGLE call to `stream.print()` to send the data.  It looks like it is trying to send it as soon as possible to prevent delays and this is what is causing fragmentation..

Comment: Yes indeed. Anyway I prefer a byte buffer so I do not fear to send zeros (C-style string terminator). I posted my final solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you can join strings into one string by separating with a sign (i.e."-") and then split it into array elements

Comment: This is just a duplicate of Code Gorilla's answer from a year and a half earlier.

Comment: It will a better answer is you added a code sample.